# :bootclasspath causes java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, clojure, javaagents, bootclasspath

I'm trying to compile my project with :bootclasspath set to true, so as to have the jar for a java agent added to my classpath, but in one of my projects it's generating java.lang.NullPointerException on this line:

```
(def app (middleware/wrap-base #'app-base))
```

which is preceded by:

```
(defroutes base-routes
           (route/resources "/")
           (route/not-found "Not Found"))

(def app-base
  (routes
    (var service-routes)
    (wrap-routes #'home-routes middleware/wrap-csrf)
    #'base-routes))
```

The full backtrace is:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException, compiling:(handler.clj:86:10)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler$InvokeExpr.eval(Compiler.java:3628)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler$DefExpr.eval(Compiler.java:439)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.compile1(Compiler.java:7323)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:7390)
    at clojure.lang.RT.compile(RT.java:399)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:444)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:412)
    at clojure.core$load$fn__5448.invoke(core.clj:5866)
    at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5865)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5671)
    at clojure.core$load_lib$fn__5397.invoke(core.clj:5711)
    at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5710)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:632)
    at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5749)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:632)
    at clojure.core$require.doInvoke(core.clj:5832)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:482)
    at projectx.core$loading__5340__auto____21.invoke(core.clj:3)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:152)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:144)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler$InvokeExpr.eval(Compiler.java:3623)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.compile1(Compiler.java:7323)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.compile1(Compiler.java:7313)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:7390)
    at clojure.lang.RT.compile(RT.java:399)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:444)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:412)
    at clojure.core$load$fn__5448.invoke(core.clj:5866)
    at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5865)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5671)
    at clojure.core$compile$fn__5453.invoke(core.clj:5877)
    at clojure.core$compile.invoke(core.clj:5876)
    at user$eval9$fn__16.invoke(form-init8240839476947253640.clj:1)
    at user$eval9.invoke(form-init8240839476947253640.clj:1)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6782)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6772)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7227)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.loadFile(Compiler.java:7165)
    at clojure.main$load_script.invoke(main.clj:275)
    at clojure.main$init_opt.invoke(main.clj:280)
    at clojure.main$initialize.invoke(main.clj:308)
    at clojure.main$null_opt.invoke(main.clj:343)
    at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:421)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:421)
    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:383)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:156)
    at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:700)
    at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.webjars.WebJarAssetLocator.listParentURLsWithResource(WebJarAssetLocator.java:66)
    at org.webjars.WebJarAssetLocator.getAssetPaths(WebJarAssetLocator.java:84)
    at org.webjars.WebJarAssetLocator.getFullPathIndex(WebJarAssetLocator.java:121)
    at org.webjars.WebJarAssetLocator.<init>(WebJarAssetLocator.java:152)
    at ring.middleware.webjars$wrap_webjars.invoke(webjars.clj:27)
    at ring.middleware.webjars$wrap_webjars.invoke(webjars.clj:25)
    at projectx.middleware$wrap_base.invoke(middleware.clj:90)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:154)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:144)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler$InvokeExpr.eval(Compiler.java:3623)
    ... 51 more
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException, compiling:(handler.clj:86:10)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler$InvokeExpr.eval(Compiler.java:3628)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler$DefExpr.eval(Compiler.java:439)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.compile1(Compiler.java:7323)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:7390)
    at clojure.lang.RT.compile(RT.java:399)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:444)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:412)
    at clojure.core$load$fn__5448.invoke(core.clj:5866)
    at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5865)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5671)
    at clojure.core$load_lib$fn__5397.invoke(core.clj:5711)
    at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5710)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:632)
    at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5749)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:632)
    at clojure.core$require.doInvoke(core.clj:5832)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:482)
    at projectx.core$loading__5340__auto____21.invoke(core.clj:3)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:152)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:144)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler$InvokeExpr.eval(Compiler.java:3623)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.compile1(Compiler.java:7323)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.compile1(Compiler.java:7313)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:7390)
    at clojure.lang.RT.compile(RT.java:399)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:444)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:412)
    at clojure.core$load$fn__5448.invoke(core.clj:5866)
    at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5865)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5671)
    at clojure.core$compile$fn__5453.invoke(core.clj:5877)
    at clojure.core$compile.invoke(core.clj:5876)
    at user$eval9$fn__16.invoke(form-init8240839476947253640.clj:1)
    at user$eval9.invoke(form-init8240839476947253640.clj:1)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6782)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6772)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7227)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.loadFile(Compiler.java:7165)
    at clojure.main$load_script.invoke(main.clj:275)
    at clojure.main$init_opt.invoke(main.clj:280)
    at clojure.main$initialize.invoke(main.clj:308)
    at clojure.main$null_opt.invoke(main.clj:343)
    at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:421)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:421)
    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:383)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:156)
    at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:700)
    at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.webjars.WebJarAssetLocator.listParentURLsWithResource(WebJarAssetLocator.java:66)
    at org.webjars.WebJarAssetLocator.getAssetPaths(WebJarAssetLocator.java:84)
    at org.webjars.WebJarAssetLocator.getFullPathIndex(WebJarAssetLocator.java:121)
    at org.webjars.WebJarAssetLocator.<init>(WebJarAssetLocator.java:152)
    at ring.middleware.webjars$wrap_webjars.invoke(webjars.clj:27)
    at ring.middleware.webjars$wrap_webjars.invoke(webjars.clj:25)
    at projectx.middleware$wrap_base.invoke(middleware.clj:90)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:154)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:144)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler$InvokeExpr.eval(Compiler.java:3623)
    ... 51 more
Compilation failed: Subprocess failed
```

Any ideas what's going on here?